# NSURLConnection Download File In another class

Tags: ios4, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I can manage to download something with using NSURLConnection however I want to use a another class to return NSURLConnection result (NSData). I couldn't manage that.

Lets say I have this  class:

```
@interface testData : NSData
@end
```

And I have implemented NSURLConnection, the process can download also i can see the data is there when connectionDidFinishLoading triggered. but I can't return data to my main class. I hope i can tell what I need. thank you.

```
@implementation testData

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   //doSomething
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save a reference to a delegate (the object that you want to send the data to) then make a method in that delegate that accepts a NSData * object.

testData.h

```
@interface testData : NSData
    TestDataDelegate * delegate;
    NSMutableData * receivedData;

@end
```

testData.m
@implementation testData

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   [delegate doSomethingWithData:receivedData];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //be sure to alloc/init receivedData when you create the connection.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

@end
```

TestDataDelegate.h

```
@interface TestDataDelegate : NSData
@end
-(void)doSomethingWithData:(NSData *)data;
```

TestDataDelegate.m

```
-(void)doSomethingWithData:(NSData *)data
{
 //dosomethingwith data
}
```

Comment: doSomethingWithData didn't trigger. TestDataDelegate is type of UIViewController, does it matter?

Comment: no it doesn't, is it valid in the context, set a brakepoint after.

Comment: yes, while i am typing [delegate doSome... it appears but somehow it is not being called. weird.

Comment: i mean is it alloc/inited like, if(delate = nil){assert(0);}

Comment: aggghhh, it was around 3am i think i had brain fever. it works and flawless. i am thank you so much.